# How to let c++ program DON'T wait the adb feedback

Tags: android, c++, shell

My c++ program call the adb.exe for screenrecord for 10sec:

```
system("adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 --time-limit 10 /sdcard/kitkat.mp4");
```

This program will stay and wait until the adb shell command is finished.
However, I want the program that don't wait for the adb process finished, but keep excute other function.

I don't know hoe to do that. Please help and thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are on linux you can use `popen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it in another thread, you can read about the thread library of c++ [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/)

should be something like:

Main program:

```
...
std::thread first (foo); 
...
```

and define foo:

```
returnType foo(){
    system("adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 --time-limit 10 /sdcard/kitkat.mp4");
    *return something if you want to*
```

P.S. sorry if foo function isnt accurate, my c++ is a bit rusty